# Why can't I see my .txt file from this php script

Tags: php

I'm using this script to see the content of a .text file -

```
<?php

$file = fopen("Gin_List_Website.txt","r");

if(!file)
{
    echo("ERROR:cant open file .. :(");
}
else
{
    echo("opened the file .. :)");

    $buff = fread ($file,filesize("Gin_List_Website.txt"));
    print $buff;
    echo $buff;
}
?>
```

But all I see is this line

> opened the file .. :)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you just want the full file why not use `file` or `file_get_contents`?

Comment: change if(!file) to if(!$file)

Comment: @bharatparmar I missed that, and now its giving the error ..

Comment: can you show the error ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the "ERROR:cant open file .. :(" in the .php script. I have the php file in the same directory as my .text file

Comment: did you check the "Gin_List_Website.txt" file exist with proper path and name ? ..its working fine here!

Comment: `if(!file)` is always `TRUE`. You probably meant `if (! $file)`. After you fix that you will probably receive the `ERROR:cant open file` message that explains why the `print` statement doesn't print anything.

Comment: It was my mistake as in the answer below, miss spelt "Gin_List_Website.txt" with a lowercase 'l' on the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change if(!file) with if(!$file).

Here is more simple code example:

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("Gin_list_Website.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($file,filesize("Gin_list_Website.txt"));
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: I get the 'unable to open file!' error, I have the php file in the same directory as my .text file

Comment: Do you have set right permissions to your "Gin_List_Website.txt" file ? What's your text file name and extension ?

Comment: this is the path to the .txt file .. http://www.thelabmultiplayer.com/ewExternalFiles/Gin_list_Website.txt

Comment: You have problem with filename. You have uppercase "L" in php code and real filename has small letter "l". I updated answer code and you can try.